# In what sense is the chiral decomposition of spinors unique?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, clifford-algebra

We may decompose a spinor field $\psi = \psi_L + \psi_R$ where $\psi_L = \frac12 (1 - \gamma^5) \psi$ and $\psi_R = \frac12 (1 + \gamma^5) \psi$. (I believe this is because the clifford algebra has completely reducible representations?) Is this the *only* way for us to decompose the spinor into left and right handed parts? Or, rather, is there some other way for us to write down $\psi = \psi_L + \psi_R$?

Comment: left and right handed spinors are *defined* that way, and the explicit structure of them also depends on the repesentation of the gamma matrices used.

Comment: The way you wrote it, we have $\psi=\psi_L+\psi_R$. But we can also write $a\psi_L=\tfrac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)\psi$ and similarly for $\psi_R$. Then we have a linear combination $\psi=a\psi_L+b\psi_R$. Also, as mentioned by glance, the representation we use matters. $a,b$ are complex constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left-handed and right-handed spinors are defined as being eigenstates of $\gamma_5$ with eigenvalues $-1$ and $+1$ respectively. The vector space of spinor states is a direct sum the subspace of states of left-handed spinors and the subspace of right-handed spinors. The operators $P_L=\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)$ and $P_R=\frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)$ are the unique projectors on these subspaces. Therefore, the decomposition of a spinor into its left- and right-handed parts is unique and you can get the left- and right-handed parts by acting on the spinor with the projectors $P_L$ and $P_R$.

To check the statements above

1. Verify that $\gamma^5$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$.
2. Show that $P_L$ and $P_R$ obey $P_L^2=P_L$ and $P_R^2=P_R$ (the definition of projectors).
3. Show that $\gamma^5 P_L\psi=-P_L\psi$ and $\gamma^5 P_R\psi=P_R\psi$ for any $\psi$ which tells you that the projectors do indeed project on the desired eigenspaces.

For these you will have to use $(\gamma^5)^2=1$.